# How are 'Most Heroic Attack' and 'Most Heroic Defence' determined in a clan war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When you open the clan war menu and press the little star at the top of the screen for war info, at the bottom of the 'War Stats' tab it has featured battles, showing 'Most Heroic Attack' and 'Most Heroic Defense'. How does it determine these? By the skill (not sure what else to call it) difference between the players, which is used to rank the players in a clan during a clan war?

Answer (score 1):

I have got most heroic attack 8/10 times. The attacks that received it were when I attacked someone close to the same number as me (if I am tenth from the top in my clan I attacked someone close to that #) or stronger, I got a 3 star/100% win and I won it with less than 10 secs left. The time probably doesn't have anything to do with it but that has been the case in each of the wins. I just wish you could get a bonus for getting most heroic...Sigh

Also they have never been someone more than 5 spaces below my number. I use a combination of Wizards, archers, barbs and minions to take out cc troops and barb king, two groups of about 15 hogs (about 30 total hogs) and 3 Healing spells for those hogs. Hope this helps and gl.

Answer (score 1):

It is determined by recommended on the map, so if your recommended target is #30 and you attack (and win against) a player 10 higher than your recommended target(#20), and no other player attacks someone 10 positions higher than their recommended target, then you get most heroic attack.

Most heroic defense is if you win a defense against a player who attacked the lowest compared to his/her recommended target, for example a player in the other clan has a recommended target 10 higher than you are. If he attacks you and loses, and nobody else got attacked by a player that has a recommended target 10 higher than they are, you get most heroic defense

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that it is a combination of the skill levels of the players, and the success of the attack/defence.

i.e. A player with a low skill level that destroys 50% of a high level base might earn more rep than a high skill level player that flattens a low level base, and reverse for defence.

Answer (score 0):

after trying to figure it out ive come to the conclusion that the most heroic is awarded to the person that attacks the highest skill difference between them and the enemy and gets at least one star. the amount of stars received seems to have no effect on most heroic.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found in personal experience is...

---

```
Most Heroic Attack
```

Let's say you are #5 out of 10 players in a clan war.  Now you attack #4 and you three star him, now you have Most Heroic Attack.  Now the only way somebody can take that away is if they attacked somebody has to attack above their equal and Gain the three stars on that player (100% the player that has to have <50% on his base & > His Equal)... So lets say your #4 attacks their #2 and gains the Three Stars off of his untouched base, now he has the Most Heroic Attack.

**You have to get the stars!**

*I was #10 and I gained 95% to their #7 and didn't get any stars on him (He was already 3 stared by my #6), and I DID NOT get Most Heroic Attack.*

---

```
Most Heroic Defense
```

I'll try to make this one more Brief... MHD (Most Heroic Defense) is determined by who defended the attacker's offense the best.  let's say you (#5 out of 10) is attacked by #4 (out of their 10) and the attacker (them) only gets 45% and misses the TH (Town Hall).  This is considered a Defended attack.  You will have the MHD as long as somebody 1 space above their equal doesn't fail an attack.

- another example... your #10 defends and attack from their #8, now sense 8 is two spaces above 10 you lose MHD and your #10 gains it.

---

This is entirely out of personal experience over that last 1 & 1/2 years of Clashing.